# internal server error on git server when increasing maxAllowedContentLength and maxRequestLength

Tags: git, bonobo

Whenever I try to increase  and  inside web.config and try to connect to our git server afterwards I get a internal error 500. Does anyone know why its so sensitive to changing these values? I want to be able to push code which exceeds a couple of MB because I want to push a demo file which has the size of 4GB to the server. Other members should be able to pull this file.

I tried researching the reasons for that to throw any error and look into any existing logfiles which could get me more insight, but they dont provide any further insight to the problem.